# JQuery mobile multiple pages with php

Tags: php, jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I am developing my first jquery mobile web app, and am trying to understand the relationship of server-side (PHP) code relating to multiple pages in one HTML file.

In this case I have a single html file which contains all of my various pages for the web app: index, login, register, settings, etc (just the front end, all of the actual data requests are  handled via P.R.G.). Based on whichever #page is displayed, can I nest my PHP code within the #page div to be run only when that #page div is called, or does ALL of the php run regardless of which page div is called?

example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index"  data-theme="b">
<?php $this is some thing that is pertinent only to elements within the #index page.?>
</div> <!--#index -->


<div data-role="page" id="login"  data-theme="b">
<?php $this is something that is only pertinent to the login page, and will NOT play nice with the other php code in the page.?>
</div> <!-- #login -->
```

Would BOTH of those php items run, or would only the item in the active #page div run?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: php has no concept of html. it's just text, really. php will not "see" your data-role, it'll just excecute **ANYTHING** inside `<?php ?>` blocks. if you want only one of those blocks to "run", then you'll need the appropriate `if()`-type logic at the time the page is built on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on what @Marc B said, when a PHP file is run, it goes through from top to bottom, outputting plain text (text outside  tags) and executing the PHP script (running the PHP functions and outputting the printed results).

So in your example, both PHP code blocks would be executed if there were no errors produced. As it is now, the first block would produce an error and stop processing.

A good way to get your head around the concept of server-side vs client-side coding would be to go through the w3schools PHP tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/php/